# Is it grammatically correct to say 'interrupting the perspective'?

Tags: grammaticality, word-request

The context I want to use it in is as follows:

> There were no partitions separating one division from another either.
>   The only things **interrupting the perspective** in places, were the
>   columns supporting the ceiling.

I'm trying to say that 'the office was wide and there were **only** the columns supporting the ceiling that cut the perspective **in places**.'

Comment: *Perspective* is rarely used in this sense; it usually designates either a literal or figurative *viewpoint* or the technical art of constructing a sketch or painting as seen from a particular viewpoint. I've edited your title to reflect what you actually ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would likely use the phrase ***interrupting the view***.

That seems to be a rather common way to express this:

> Washington flanked the entry gates with mounds and ha-ha walls, hidden harriers that keep cattle from the bowling green without **interrupting the view** from the house. (*Gardens of America: Three Centuries of Design*, by D.K. McGuire)
>
> Already, pallets of glazed brick stacked higher than a man's head stood at random, **interrupting the view** across the open floor. (*Empire State*, E.A. Pollitz)
>
> The Culzean viaduct was to have had towers along its length but their superstructures, **interrupting the view** to the castle, were omitted. (*Masterpieces of Architectural Drawing*, H. Powell & D. Leatherbarrow)

With that backdrop, I'd say:

> There were no partitions separating one division from another; the only things interrupting the view were the columns supporting the ceiling.

Comment: You can also say "blocking the view".

Answer (score 2):

One of the three meanings given from the OALD for *interrupt* is, "to stop a line, surface, view, etc. from being even or continuous." (In Italian we have a similar expression which involves *interrompere*, the Italian translation for *interrupt*.)

I would avoid writing *in places*, since that seems implicit, to me; if the view would be completely *interrupted*, I would use a different word, such as *obscured*, or *hidden*.

Answer (score 2):

As an English native speaker, I would probably say **Getting in the way of the view**, or **obscuring the view**.

Alternatively, I might refer to the offending items as **eyesores**.